# Add image to drawable folder with relative path in android

Tags: android, android-studio

I want to add some images to the `drawable` folder in `Android Studio`.
My problem is that I don't know how to add them from a relative path.
And is it the right way to add an `ImageAsset` or is there an other solution?
In my project, I have a `pics` folder and I want to add the pictures from this folder to the drawable folder. It looks like that:

[image]

And how can I invoke these images in the code?

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:id="@+id/btnRecordVideo"
        />
```

android:background and how would the path look like?

Answer (score 1):

Copy all the pictures to the app\src\main\res\drawable directory (create the folder if it does not exist). To refer to them in xml, use @drawable/file_name.

Comment: I can't copy and paste to this folder so what should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

Copy the images and right click on android studio ide and paste inside drawable folder:

call it in xml as img:src: @drawable/filename.jpg
Hope it helps